# How can I create a javascript object depending on react state

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects

I want to create javascript objects as below depedning on my reast state where those states that have not changed or are zero are ignored. I am trying to create a function to do this but I am not able to do so.

```
// different javascript objects depending on the state
{ bedroomCount: 3, bathroomCount: 2 }
{ bathroomCount: 2 , parkingCount: 1 }
{ bedroomCount: 1, bathroomCount: 1 , parkingCount: 1 }
{ parkingCount: 1 }
```

React state as below

```
const [bedroomCount, setBedroomCount] = useState(0);    
const [bathroomCount, setBathroomCount] = useState(0);
const [parkingCount, setParkingCount] = useState(0);
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? What exactly is your problem? Here is a suggestion:
`const createStateObject = () => {
    const stateObject = {};

    if (bedroomCount > 0) {
        stateObject.bedroomCount = bedroomCount;
    }

    if (bathroomCount > 0) {
        stateObject.bathroomCount = bathroomCount;
    }

    if (parkingCount > 0) {
        stateObject.parkingCount = parkingCount;
    }

    return stateObject;
}`

Comment: @EmadMamaghani I am trying to create url for eg. ```/rent/newyork/?bedrooms=1&bathrooms=1``` or ```/rent/california/?bedrooms=2&parking=1``` depening on filters that users have selected. I will need createSearchParams which needs object to create the filters. I will try your example and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `if` statements:

```
let obj = {}
if(bedroomCount) obj.bedroomCount = bedroomCount
if(bathroomCount) obj.bathroomCount = bathroomCount
if(parkingCount) obj.parkingCount = parkingCount
console.log(obj)
```

But it does not include the case of "states that have not changed" though, please provide more information.